# Ionic - How to set <Ion-scroll> height so that it automatically adjusts in all resolution devices?

Tags: ionic-framework

My code is as follows:

```
<ion-scroll style="height:200px;">
<ion-item  ng-repeat="items in Items" >
<!--repeat group-->
</ion-item>
</ion-scroll>
```

I have a scroll view of height = 200px, this looks ok on small devices, but when I view this on large device, the content appears too small because the height is  '200px' which is comparatively small. So, what's the proper method of fixing this? I tried using height in percentages but it did not fix. Please, help and sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 18):

Use `vh` unit instead of `px`.You can set `vh` value from 1 to 100, 100 vh means full screen size. Your code will be:

```
<ion-scroll style="height:100vh;">
```

or if `height` does not work then

```
<ion-scroll style="max-height:100vh;">
```

Usefull [link](http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/vm-vh-units) about styling with `vh`.

Comment: Hi, I tried your solution but it did not help. When I fix the height in small device, I still see the content small on large device.

Comment: you need to give percentage height to `items` inside scoll view. For example 20vh to each item.

Comment: Suppose I use 100vh on small device and it covers the whole sceen, the same 100vh does not cover whole screen on large device. So, I don't think it will solve the problem

Comment: @BiswasKhayargoli-ITH i think you did not went through document i mentioned. `vh` unit is used to measure with total size of screen. 100vh means 100% height of total screen height. Please see again http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/vm-vh-units

Comment: Yes, I did the same, now try the same code in larger device and you will see some spaces remaining at the bottom of the page, as it wont cover the whole page.

Comment: what more screen size can be than the demo i showed you. May be you should put your code on http://play.ionic.io/ so i can see what wrong are you doing.

Answer (score 0):

Here what did i do, 
in your scroll, wrap it with this class: `modal-parent`, `modal-top`, `modal-scroll`

```
<ion-modal-view class="modal-parent">

  <ion-item class="modal-top">
    ...
  </ion-item>

  <ion-scroll class="modal-scroll" style="height:100px;width:100%;"...>
    ...
  </ion-scroll>

</ion-modal-view>
```

in you js define this function:

```
  function setScrollHeight(parent, top, scroll, index, offset){
    var parentH = document.getElementsByClassName(parent)[index].clientHeight;
    var topH = document.getElementsByClassName(top)    [index].clientHeight;
    var scrollH = document.getElementsByClassName(scroll)[index];

    scrollH.style.height = parentH - topH - offset + 'px';
  }
```

and you are ready to go by calling something like this

`setScrollHeight('modal-parent', 'modal-top', 'modal-scroll',1 ,100);`

basically, `modal-parent` will minus `modal-top` and the result will set `modal-scroll`'s height

`offset` something like padding