# How to stop column scrolling in ionic

Tags: list, ionic-framework, ionic2, multiple-columns

I am working on a screen on which there are two columns, one to select the category and another column is to display items according to the category, basically a filtering option screen. I have two columns, category column has 3 options cat 1, cat 2 and cat 3, and the list on the other column is bigger and can be scroll-able and different list for different category. But I'm unable to do so. When I scroll on this screen the whole screen is scrolling the category column too. I want to stop category column from scrolling and the item column can be scroll-able. how to do it? my code is below...

```
<ion-content>

    <ion-row>
  <ion-col >

    <ion-item>
      cat1
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item>
      cat2
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item>
      cat3
    </ion-item>
  </ion-col>

  <ion-col class="home-container">

      <ion-list>
          <ion-item padding text-wrap *ngFor="let d of data">
              <ion-label>
                   {{ d.title }} 
              </ion-label>
              <ion-checkbox color="royal" checked="false"></ion-checkbox>
          </ion-item>
      </ion-list>

  </ion-col>
</ion-row>

</ion-content>
```

css

```
page-teacher-filter {
    .home-container {
        overflow:auto;
        height: 100%;
   }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Your item column need to have a height and `overflow:auto` to achieve this

Comment: @sTx not working.. see i have updated question..

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/32458828/7784663

Comment: @TusharKotecha thanks its working now..

Answer (score 1):

You need a fixed height

```css
section{
  background:red;
  padding: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.cat_1, .cat_2{
  float: left;
  padding: 20px;
}
.cat_1{background: silver;}
.cat_2{
  background: white;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="cat_1">
    <div>item1</div>
    <div>item2</div>
    <div>item3</div>
  </div>

  <div class="cat_2">
    <div>item1</div>
    <div>item2</div>
    <div>item3</div>
    <div>item1</div>
    <div>item2</div>
    <div>item3</div>
    <div>item1</div>
    <div>item2</div>
    <div>item3</div>
    <div>item1</div>
    <div>item2</div>
    <div>item3</div>
    <div>item1</div>
    <div>item2</div>
    <div>item3</div>
    <div>item1</div>
    <div>item2</div>
    <div>item3</div>
    <div>item1</div>
    <div>item2</div>
    <div>item3</div>
    <div>item1</div>
    <div>item2</div>
    <div>item3</div>
    <div>item1</div>
    <div>item2</div>
    <div>item3</div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: how can i provide height as device screen size ?